# Location of Vector's hideout

Tags: plot-explanation, alita-battle-angel

When Alita goes to confront Vector in his HQ, she battles into the hunter-warrior HQ, but then crashes down through the glass ceiling into Vector's penthouse(?) suite.

*Why does she crash in through the glass roof and not appear from the door (if she took a lift or something)? Surely if she was going to break through the glass roof, it would be better to scale the outside of the building?*